# The supremum-like definition of greatest common divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have reasonable experience with analysis, but I have just recently begun studying abstract algebra from Dummit and Foote.

I am frightened that I am already getting tripped up on pp.4, with the definition of *greatest common divisor*.

My intuitive understanding of *greatest common divisor*, from grade school, would be the maximal common element of two integers' factor trees.   I am having trouble aligning this with Dummit and Foote's definition, which parallels the definition of a supremum.

First, they make a predefinition:  if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \neq 0$, then they say $a$ divides $b$, or $a|b$, if $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z} : b= ac$.

Then, they proceed with the definition: if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$, then there exists a unique positive integer $d$, called the *greatest common divisor* of $a$ and $b$, satisfying:

1. $d | a$ and $d | b$ (so $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$)
2. if $e|a$ and $e|b$ then $e|d$ (so $d$ is the greatest such divisor)

Now I can't actually figure out how to prove the second property.

What I mean is that, suppose I assume $d|a$,$d|b$,$e|a$,$e|b$.  Then why does $d>e \implies e|d$?

Comment: Are you asking for a formal proof or an intuitive explanation?

Comment: I was going to say that I would have appreciated either, but Sasha's answer completely cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g$ be the gcd of $a$ and $b$. The we can write
$$a=m*g$$
$$b=n*g$$
Where $m$ and $n$ are co-prime ie their gcd is 1. ( This is evident ). Now let us assume $e$ divides both $a$ and $b$. Then $e$ can't be a divisor of $m$ and $n$ because they are co-prime , it means $e$ has to be a divisor of $g$ so that it can divide both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Was so confused in this issue.